# How can i write python decorator for caching?

Tags: python, caching, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to write python decorator for memoize. 
I have few questions.

1. How does @memoize translate to memoize class's **call** function?
2. Why does **init** expect an argument.
3. Where is the cache stored? Is it associated with each and every function or it's a global variable? i.e Will there be two cache objects if i use @memoize for 
   multiple functions.

..

```
class memoize:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}

    def __call__(self, function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            key = str(function.__name__) + str(args) + str(kwargs)
            if key in cache:
                return cache[key]
            else:
                value = function(*args, **kwargs)
                cache[key] = value
                return value
        return wrapper

@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n in (0, 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

for i in range(0, 10):
    print(fib(i))
```

I'm getting compilation error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "memoize.py", line 17, in <module>
    @memoize
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Do you really want to write this from scratch?

Comment: Yes. I'm learning python decorators

Comment: Ok, just double checking, as there is a `lru_cache` decorator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You should remember that `@decorator` is just a syntactic sugar for `func = decorator(func)`. So here comes a difference:

(1)

```
@decorator 
def func():
     ...
```

is same as

```
func = decorator(func)  # Just call of __init__
func(...)               # Call of decorator.__call__
```

but (2)

```
@decorator(some_param)
def func():
     ...
```

is similiar to

```
# Call of __init__ plus call of __call__
func = decorator(some_param)(func)  
# Call of closure returned by decorator.__call__
func(...)
```

2. You have implemented decorator accepting arguments for (2) syntax, but do not provide them when using them as in example (1). That is why `__init__` complaining, it receives `func` as second argument.
3. You should write `self.cache` in a `wrapper` closure, so `wrapper` would reference corresponding `decorator` object. Writing just `cache` will cause global variable search and thus will fail.

**UPD**: I changed your code to approach (1):

```
class memoize:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.cache = {}
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        key = str(args) + str(kwargs)
        if key in self.cache:
            return self.cache[key]

        value = self.function(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cache[key] = value
        return value

@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n in (0, 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

for i in range(0, 10):
    print(fib(i))

print(fib.cache)
```

Comment: If you see this example, https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize cache is a member variable of class memoize. No wrappers around

Comment: I've changed your approach to (1) and posted code, but I suggest you should carefully read my explanation.

Comment: Okay. How should add a ttl now?
I would like to use @memoize(ttl=10). I tried adding a parameter to __init__ function in the class and got error again

Comment: He-he, I'd expected you to ask this. Than you need to change code from approach (1) to (2). Use your original code (but change `cache` -> `self.cache`). See my answer to your second question.

Comment: So this is where i get confused. 
There are two types of decorator syntax i have to remember then.
1. For memoize without specifying any arguments.
2. For memoize with ttl.

Comment: This is an extremely useful Python decorator for lots of applications.  Thanks for sharing!